# Django often returns outdated view

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, flup

I'm pretty new to web development (not to programming), but I just successfully (sort of) deployed a really basic hello-world style Django app.  The first time I did it, I had an issue in my HTML.  Here's my whole view with the error:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def homepage(request):
  now=datetime.datetime.now()
  html="<html><body><It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
  return HttpResponse(html)
```

The extra < just after the first body tag caused the browser to display a blank page.  I figured out what I did and fixed the error.  I also added a title so I'd be able to track what's going on (somewhat) better.  The old view became this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def homepage(request):
  now=datetime.datetime.now()
  html="<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
  return HttpResponse(html)
```

Now the browser displays the old view (a blank page) most of the time, just the title with a blank body sometimes, and occasionally the whole correct new view.  I have no clue what's going on.  I'm running nginx with flup to handle the FastCGI.  Ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: And in case you have renamed the module delete the pyc files.. `find . -type f -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm -rf;`

Comment: Yes, assuming you mean nginx.

Comment: And I've also gone through and deleted the pyc files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing your code you need to restart your FastCGI server, not Nginx.